# master detail view for iPhone screen in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am new to xamarin and was creating the initial page of the application for iPhone. I added a new project with master-detail template and run it. Now on storyboard I can see both master and detail views. When I debug it for iPad on simulator it works fine and show two screens side by side when required but when I debug it for iPhone it display single screen at a time.

How can I make two pages(master-detail) visible at a time in case of iPhone ?

Comment: You'll have to create a custom UI using Size Classes. Master-Detail on iPhone will automatically adjust to a table with an accompanying detail view (2 separate screens)

Comment: Could you please suggest any reference for the same.